# Missing images after CSV import - Prestashop v1.6.1.3

Tags: csv

Hope you help. I've had to take my shop/business out of action and desperately need some help.

I did a repricing on my product range with a delete all products and import via csv import. Now i have some/most of my images missing. I have 2 images for each product and it mainly seems to be the first image that is mostly missing.

I checked:

- that the images are on my hosting server - all good
- that the image location link on the csv is correct - all good
- ensured that the missing art sizes are roughly the same size
- cleared my cashe
- changed permissions of the image files to 777
- re-uploaded my images to a new directory on my hosting server and changed permissions of all the image files to 777 and edited the link in the csv
- deleted my .htaccess
- changed to friendly urls
- change back to 'non' friendly url's
- regenerating thumbnails
- changed seo & url - Redirect to the canonical URL is set: no redirection
- changed seo & url - Redirect to the canonical URL is set: 302 Moved temp
- changed seo & url - Redirect to the canonical URL is set: 301 Moved perm
- created a tools.php file in override/classes (changing back & forward from friendly urls)

Massive thanks in advance for any help

[Back-office Product pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wovvg.png)

Comment: Have you tried asking Prestashop support? Or in their forums? [Forums Ecommerce - PrestaShop](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/)

Comment: yes but no one got back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is cause by the hosting providers php.ini file settings (that you might not be able to change). When uploading new products via csv import the thumbnails must be regenerated otherwise 'some' of the products may not have any product photos. As a work around you have two choices:

**Choice 1.** 
You can split you csv file up into 10-20 product item chunks. This chunk size appears to be dependent on the hosting providers php.ini setting. If you get a timeout then you must reduce your chunk size and re-upload. Note ensure you check your product list to ensure your not overwriting products during the last time out failure. iPAGE sql timeout seems to be around 1 hour so if you leave a gap between uploads then u can increase your chunk size (for me up to 90 product items).

Ensure you have skip thumbnail regeneration set to no.   [image]

**Choice 2.**
If you rename the image files and upload them to a new directory on the hosting/server and link to that directory from the csv file the images link and the issue resolves. A lot of work.

Hope this helps someone